# Problem with adding bgp communities to qfx

Tags: juniper-junos

I have a juniper QFX5100 and we have BGP with Telia/Arelion and here is our policy satements:

```
set policy-options community Telia-Blackhole members 1299:666
set policy-options policy-statement Telia-OUT term 10 from community DT-Blackhole
set policy-options policy-statement Telia-OUT term 10 then community set Telia-Blackhole
```

when i want to apply other bgp communties i should create them one by one but in other switches like as cisco there is no need to create them, also, telia has more than 200 bgp communities so it is hard to create all of them or even if i add another upstream i can not create all of their communities.

i think i am configuring something wrong, any idea how to solve this?

Comment: here is my cisco config : route-map Telia-Backup-OUT permit 10
  match community DT-Blackhole
  set community 1299:666